Springboot3 with Hibernate6 error with class not found SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
springboot 3.24
hibernete 6.44
jdk 21
error with:
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
Searched on internet that SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy was deprecated, using CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy instead.
but I still failed after I updated the settings ,
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
        #physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
        #physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        #physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        #implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy

I tried to generate a totally new project by using spring initializr, copy only database related codes in it, and it also failed.

Just remove those settings, they are the defaults already.

finally fixed,
the correct config was:
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
properties.put("hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");
properties.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy");

first, using MySQLDialect instead of MySQL5InnoDBDialect, it's deleted.
second,using "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy" not springframework jar.
